# SQL statement improve for speed

Tags: php, sql, foreach

i have this piece of code that selects all users from the table and another sql statement that counts the number of records for every user. the problem I'm facing is that i have a sql in a foreach loop which is not good for performance but i wasn't able to combine both of them in one statement. any advise?

```
$query = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM users");
foreach($query as $v){
    $tpl->setCurrentBlock('useri');
    $query2 = $db->numRows("SELECT * FROM signups AS s INNER JOIN users AS u ON s.userid=u.id WHERE u.id={$v['id']}");
    $tpl->setVariable('total',$query2);
    $tpl->setVariable($v);
    $tpl->parseCurrentBlock();
}
```

Comment: Please include the table structure for both the users table and the signups table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query against your DB:

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(s.*)
  FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN signups s ON s.userid = u.id
  GROUP BY u.id
```

I hope I got it right. I have no SQL DB to test it right here. Important: You have to group by each field you select that is no aggregate.

**Edit:**

If it is not fast enough yet, an index on `signups.userid` may help. This is hypothetic, however, so you should check the Execution Plan your query engine generates.

Comment: i have an index on signups.userid Query took 0.0009 sec

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $db->getAll("
   SELECT u.id, u.name, COUNT(*) total
     FROM signups AS s RIGHT JOIN users AS u ON s.userid=u.id 
 GROUP BY u.id, u.name
 ORDER BY u.name
");

foreach($query as $v){
    $tpl->setCurrentBlock('useri');
    $tpl->setVariable('total', $query['total']);
    // ...
    $tpl->parseCurrentBlock();
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `INNER JOIN` omits `users` rows with no corresponding `signups` instead of bringing them up with a count of zero.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand good your problem, initialize variable and in loop increase it.

```
int i;
foreach($query as $v){
$tpl->setCurrentBlock('useri');
$query2 = $db->numRows("SELECT * FROM signups AS s INNER JOIN users AS u ON s.userid=u.id WHERE u.id={$v['id']}");
$tpl->setVariable('total',$query2);
$tpl->setVariable($v);
$tpl->parseCurrentBlock();
i++;
}
```

Comment: i want to move the sql statement ouside the loop because if i have 1000k queries it will take to long